# How to append json to existing json in Elastic Search .NEST client?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, elasticsearch, nest

In my .net core application I am trying to save my request to elasticsearch using NEST client. Problem is all time it is overriding data and in the end I am getting only one latest request.

My configuration looks like:

```
    public static void AddElasticsearch(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var url = "elasticurl";
        var defaultIndex = "taikunrequests";

        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(url))
            .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);

        AddDefaultMappings(settings);

        var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

        services.AddSingleton<IElasticClient>(client);

        CreateIndex(client, defaultIndex);
    }

    private static void AddDefaultMappings(ConnectionSettings settings)
    {
        settings.
            DefaultMappingFor<TaikunRequest>(m => m
            .Ignore(p => p.Id)
        );
    }

    private static void CreateIndex(IElasticClient client, string indexName)
    {
        client.Indices.Create(indexName,
            index => index.Map<TaikunRequest>(x => x.AutoMap())
        );
    }
```

Code while saving data:

```
            var dto = new TaikunRequest
            {
                Endpoint = actionMethodName,
                OrganizationId = currentOrgId,
                OrganizationName = currentOrgName,
                RequestType = actionType,
                UserId = _userAccessor.GetCurrentUserId(),
                UserName = currentUserName,
                UserRole = _userAccessor.GetCurrentRole(),
                Ip = realIp ?? "none",
                RequestId = requestId ?? "none",
                Status = actionStatus
            };
            
            await _elasticClient.IndexDocumentAsync(dto, cancellationToken);
```

When I try to get result it is always one result:

calling   elasticurl/taikunrequests/_search

```
{
  "took": 8,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 1,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "taikunrequests",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "0",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "organizationId": 1,
          "organizationName": "itera",
          "userId": "d1c523e7-337c-42c3-9c58-83af83a71ed7",
          "userName": "arzu",
          "userRole": "admin",
          "requestType": "GET",
          "endpoint": "/api/v1/Admin/projects/list",
          "createdAt": "2021-07-19T08:34:16.9949230Z",
          "ip": "none",
          "requestId": "none",
          "status": 200
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How to append new data to current one all time?

Comment: Could you share how the class `TaikunRequest` looks like?

Comment: @Rob structure inside hits you can see. All are string fields except status and orgid is integer and createdAt is date time.

Comment: Think the issue is happening because of this `Id` prop defined in `TaikunRequest` class. All documents have `id` set to `"0"` - elasticsearch thinks all of the docs are you trying to index are the same single document.

Comment: @Rob I need to remove ignore option for id?

Comment: @Rob nope actually it does not helped, it is still same issue

Comment: You can remove `Id` prop from your type or disable [ids inference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/ids-inference.html). Depends on your use case and what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @Rob works like charm. Thanks